# Combine separate date and time columns into one column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a situation for which I need some suggestions. No code as I want to look that up and figure it out myself. This is just an academic question.

I get a flat file daily that I have to load into a table here is a snippet of the file:

```
Date-YYYMMDD  TIME
20091124|     01:19:00|...
20091124|     01:19:15|...
```

The two fields are date and time. when I load this data into the database, the results are these:

```
Date-YYYMMDD  TIME
20091124      1899-12-30 01:19:00.000
20091124      1899-12-30 01:19:15.000
```

I have a view that merges the data with the results being:

```
datetime                   yearmonthday
2009-11-24 01:19:00.000    2009-11-24
2009-11-24 01:19:15.000    2009-11-24
```

I do this effort so that the folks that need this data don't have to fool around with dates and text fields that should be dates but are not.

The problem is I don't like doing this in a view. I would rather just store it in the original table correctly. I was thinking that for every row inserted, I intercept that insert, do the merging then insert into the table in the correct format. Once done, I could drop the view. Is there a best way for this? Like any good developer/admin. I want to minimize my intervention. We have computers to do this type of work. I do not control the source file nor can I effect any changes with it. I was thinking an **on insert** trigger. Is there a better way? Though I have done a lot with TSQL over the months, I still consider myself a beginner in my understanding of good TSQL and the most efficient way to do things.

Comment: How are you loading the data into the database?

Comment: It is a fairly convoluted process that I inherited. I have made it better but it is still a manual process.

1. get files via email (I don't load everyday. it makes more sense to do it once every few days)
2. trim off some header rows and concat all files to a single file
3. load that file into an access database where all the data mapping takes place
4. import access table via sql importer to sql server

it is not a long process. I am waiting for SQLServer 2012 to be available in my environment then I will migrate and the process will get better with sis packages. I just don't have that now.

Comment: Skip Access. This is what is changing your time values to 18991230 instead of 19000101.

Comment: the problem is that the two fields a get are distinct: time and date. I have to merge them together into a true datatime. because of my version of SSIS, I don't have a time field, I only have datatime. I have heard "bulk insert" mentioned but haven't looked into it. Also, I am running SSMS 2008R2 and therefore limited with what I can do in SQLServer2005. I cannot save packages. I can only run stuff immediately I am just planning to limp along until I have the new DB. That is supposed to happen this month. They said that last month and the month before, though.

Comment: Just to clairify, the 2005 release of Integration Services *does* support a Time based data type, [DT_DBTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036(v=sql.90).aspx) It is the 2005 SQL Server database does not implement a time data type. Ultimately, fix your import package to concatenate those values into a date time datatype during the load process. That's the `T` part of `ETL` (Extract Transform and Load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say load into a staging table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StagingTable
(
  Col1 DATETIME,
  Col2 DATETIME
);
```

Load your data into this table. If your file is as simple as the one in your question, you should be able to use `BULK INSERT` and cut out much of your manual process. Then in your *real* table, have a `DATETIME` column.

```
INSERT dbo.RealTable(DateTimeColumn)
  SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, Col2), Col1)
  FROM dbo.StagingTable;

-- if successful:
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.StagingTable;
```

An even easier way would be - if you're opening the files and modifying them anyway - is to change this:

```
Date-YYYMMDD  TIME
20091124|     01:19:00|...
20091124|     01:19:15|...
```

To this:

```
Date-YYYMMDD     |...
20091124 01:19:00|...
20091124 01:19:15|...
```

Comment: so, you're saying no trigger and fix it during load time. I can do that. I have a stored procedure that does a lot of that work. it is a good idea. Sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees. Also, I will look into `bulk insert`. I will have an update shortly. **edit:** actually, I will just give the point. I can make that solution work since I have most of the structure in place already.